# Simple maths game

Tags: combinatorics

John and Peter are playing the following game: there are two different bowls, one of them contains 17 items, the other contains 12. John and Peter take turns. The rule is that in one turn they always have to take at least one item, but they can choose to take any amount, even all of them, but only from one bowl. The person taking the last item wins. Peter is first. 
Who could have a winning strategy and what is it?

For the solution: I have an idea, I think I got it right, but need your verificiation, since most of you are more experienced with mathematics than me: So my idea is: Peter has the winning strategy. Turn 1: Peter takes 5 items from the 17-bowl, making the bowls contain 12-12 items. Now for however many items John takes from a bowl, Peter will take the same amount of items from the other one, which will lead to his eventual victory.
Is this idea correct? Is there any way to prove this idea mathematically?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken is enough that the person that is second must have an even number of items in the bowl with 17. So the first person could take 1 the second will have 16. In this way as soon as only one bowl remains the game is finished... Does it help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Proof: Use induction.
1)after our first turn the bowls have the same numbers of items
2)let's consider John's turn. Before his turn there were equal numbers of items in bowls. He takes k items from one bowl. We take k from another one. We can do it because there were identical numbers of items and he managed to take k from one bowl so we can take k from another one. 
So, after our turn the numbers of items in bowls become equal and after John's - not equal. So the situation with 0 and 0 items in bowls will be after our turn.